# subset based on two condition from grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, subset

In my `data`, I'm trying to subset unique `study` values where `reporting` is both `subscale` and `composite`.

In this `data`, the desired output will be the rows of `study==1`. I have tried the following with no success. Is there any fix?

```
library(tidyverse)
m="
study  reporting
1      subscale
1      composite
2      subscale
2      subscale
3      composite"

data <- read.table(text = m, h=T)

data %>% group_by(study) %>% 
  filter(reporting=="composite"&reporting=="subscale") # Doesn't return anything
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(study) %>% 
  filter(all(c('composite', 'subscale') %in% reporting)) %>%
  ungroup()

#  study reporting
#  <int> <chr>    
#1     1 subscale 
#2     1 composite
```

Comment: In case of interest, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70312471/16762740)