# Lowercase all character columns except xyz in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, character

`foo()` is made to lowercase all character columns of a dataframe `except=` the ones whose names are provided by the user.

I wonder why when I provide `except="study"`, `foo` incorrectly lowercases the column `study` in the `data`?

Reproducible code and desired output are below.

```
m="
study cap  back
AA    L    1
BB    F    2
CC    H    8"
data <- read.table(text=m,h=T)


foo <- function(X, except = NULL){
  y <- sapply(setdiff(names(X), except), function(x) is.character(as.vector(X[[x]])))
  X[y] <- lapply(X[y], tolower)
return(X)
}
#=== EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(data, except = c("study"))

Desired_output=
"
study cap  back
AA    l    1
BB    f    2
CC    h    8"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to achieve this -

Base R -

```
foo <- function(X, except = NULL){
  y <- names(Filter(is.character, X[setdiff(names(X), except)]))
  X[y] <- lapply(X[y], tolower)
  return(X)
}
foo(data, except = c("study"))

#  study cap back
#1    AA   l    1
#2    BB   f    2
#3    CC   h    8
```

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(X, except = NULL){
  X %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.character) & 
                  all_of(setdiff(names(X), except)), tolower))
}

foo(data, except = c("study"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ronak Shah. Why doesn't this work for `data <- data.frame(Study = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), Cap = c("L", "F", "H"), Back = c(1, 2, 8)); except <- "Study"` ?

Comment: No columns are converted to lowercase if you use my example `data` and `except` and your `foo()`. Would you mind trying it yourself?

Comment: Nevermind. Sorry about that. I was thinking column names not values.

Comment: You can simplify to `across(where(is.character) & !except, tolower)`

Comment: A question of interest [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70469077/16762740).